# Is my development about the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\arctan(x)$ correct?

Tags: limits

I need to find the limit of ${\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x) }$.

My development was:

using the property that $\arctan(x) +\arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}, x > 0,$

I have:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x) + [\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(\frac{1}{x})] - [\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(\frac{1}{x})]$

$= \color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}[\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x})]} - \color{red}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(\frac{1}{x})}$

$= \color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \color{red}{0}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

If this is correct, the same procedure to prove the limit as $x\to-\infty$, but $\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac{1}{x}) = -\frac{\pi}{2}, x < 0$

Comment: Yes, though it wouldn't hurt to say "by continuity" to evaluate $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}\arctan(1/x)$.

Comment: For sin, cos, tan, cot, csc, sec, arctan, arcsin, and arccos, when formatting in mathjax, immediately precede the trig function with a backslash:  In this case `\arctan` is renders as $\arctan$ instead of $arctan$.

Comment: Thanks for that @amWhy

Answer (score 1):

The computation seems correct to me.

As a (not too much) side note, we have that the limit of the sum of two functions is the sum of the limits of the two functions *provided* that the two limits exist. Thus we first have to say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \arctan \frac 1x = 0$ by continuity, that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \arctan x$ exists because $x\mapsto \arctan x$ is monotone increasing and bounded from above. Now your computations are fully justified.